# Export a Google Sheet to Google Drive in Excel format with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-excel, google-sheets-macros

I would like to create a backup of my Google Spreadsheet into my Google Drive folder, but as an Excel file.
I managed to create a code that create a copy of the gsheet and save it into the folder, but I could not change the code to save it as an Excel file.

Could you please help me with it?

```
function makeCopy() {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm");
  var name = "Backup Copy " + formattedDate;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c")
  file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a Macro that you run on the current spreadsheet? There are some possibly better ways to implement the function if that is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

In order to convert spreadsheet to excel, the endpoint of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetId + "/export?format=xlsx` can be used. In this answer, this was used.

#### Modified script :

```
function makeCopy() {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm");
  var name = "Backup Copy " + formattedDate;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");

  // Added
  var sheetId = "2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name + ".xlsx"); // Modified
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

#### Updated: February 7, 2020

From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) So please use the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. It's as follows.

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your updated message is telling us to do. Do we still keep the `&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();` at the end? Would you mind updating your answer with the full code updated?

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. The update says that from January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. So please include the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. You can see the sample script for this in the updated question. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to tag team off of Tanaike's answer and show how to add the authentication to the header during the call.

```
function convertSheetToXLSX() {
  var sheetId = "2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c";
  var spreadsheetName = "My Spreadsheet";
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sheetId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";  
  var params = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  blob.setName(spreadsheetName + ".xlsx");
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a Simple UI to make it more useful as a day to day tool.  The top script is nearly a direct copy of MattMcCode's code.  So give him the attribution.

```
function exportSpreadsheetToXLSX(obj) {
  if (obj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    var sheetId = obj.ssid;
    var spreadsheetName = obj.filename;
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.desid);
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sheetId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(spreadsheetName + ".xlsx");
    destination.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

Just execute the below dialog to enter your ssid, folderid and filename

```
function openSpreadsheetExportToXLSXDialog() {
  let html = '';
  html += '<html><head><style> input{margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}</style></head><body>';
  html += '<form>';
  html += '<input type="text" name="ssid" size="50" placeholder="Source Spreadsheet Id" /><br />';
  html += '<input type="text" name="desid" size="50" placeholder="Destination Folder Id" /><br />';
  html += '<input type="text" name="filename" size="50" placeholder="Spreadsheet ID" /><br />';
  html += '<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode)" />';
  html += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html += '</form>';
  html += '<script>';
  html += 'function processForm(obj){console.log(obj);google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((obj)=>{google.script.host.close();}).exportSpreadsheetToXLSX(obj);}';
  html += '</script></body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Spreadsheet Export to XLSX Dialog');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

For anyone who plans on using this method in a fully automated setting, you may run into issue where the excel document is only partially filled out. This is because the UrlFetchApp isn't going to wait for computations/other SpreadSheetApp commands to complete like SpreadsheetApp or Sheets does. You can use

```
SpreadSheetApp.flush();
var blob = UrlFetchApp [...]
```

To force it to fully update sheet first.