# google sheets to zip using apps script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I am trying to make zip file from google sheets using following code in google app scripts:

```
var blobs = [];

function myFunction(){
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileId");
   var blobObject = file.getBlob();
   var blobObject1 = file.getBlob().setContentType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet").setName("blob1.xlsx");
   var blobObject2 = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel').setName("blob2.xlsx");
   var blobObject3 = file.getBlob().setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").setName("blob3.xlsx");

   blobs.push(blobObject)
   blobs.push(blobObject1)
   blobs.push(blobObject2)
   blobs.push(blobObject3)

   Logger.log(file.getMimeType());    // output : application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
   Logger.log(blobObject.getContentType())   // output : application/pdf

   Logger.log(blobObject1.getContentType()) // output : application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
   Logger.log(blobObject2.getContentType()) // output : application/vnd.ms-excel
   Logger.log(blobObject3.getContentType()) // output : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


   var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
   var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, "FolderName"+timestamp+".zip");
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderId");
   folder.createFile(zip);  

}
```

I am able to get the zip with 4 files. One file is of pdf format Reset 3 are of .xlsx format.

But unfortunately all .xlsx files are corrupted.

I am getting this error while opening .xlsx:

```
Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.
Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Please suggest how can I achieve the desirable result.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the bit that `zip`s the files? Can you open them then?

Comment: Setting the content type is **not** the same as exporting the file to that content type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a Google Sheet to Google Drive in Excel format with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963584/export-a-google-sheet-to-google-drive-in-excel-format-with-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

I was just starting to play with this yesterday when I lost internet.  So this is what I ended up doing and it works okay for me.  Thanks for the code I'll enjoy having this as I decided to learn a little more about programming in Excel.

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssId');
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var blobs = [];
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatString('Sheet%s', i + 1));
    sh.showSheet();
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        var jA=[1,2,3];
        for(var j=0;j<jA.length;j++){shts[jA[j]].hideSheet();}//hide other sheets
        shts[i].showSheet();
        blobs.push(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf'));
        break;
      case 1:
        var jA=[0,2,3];
        for(var j=0;j<jA.length;j++){shts[jA[j]].hideSheet();}//hide other sheets
        blobs.push(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName("blob1.xlsx")); 
        break;
      case 2:
        var jA=[0,1,3];
        for(var j=0;j<jA.length;j++){shts[jA[j]].hideSheet();}//hide other sheets
        blobs.push(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName("blob2.xlsx"));
        break;
      case 3:
        var jA=[0,1,2];
        for(var j=0;j<jA.length;j++){shts[jA[j]].hideSheet();}           
        blobs.push(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName("blob3.xlsx"));
        break;
    }
  }
  var timestamp = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
  var zip = Utilities.zip(blobs, "FolderName"+timestamp+".zip");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  folder.createFile(zip);  
}
```

- [Solution Came From Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49963724/7215091)