# Attach excel workbook or convert sheets into excel, then send via gmail using gscript, so that workbook is editable by recipient?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want to be able to send an email to 100+ emails that I have, with an attachment. The attachment needs to be an editable excel file for the recipients. I can access it either as excel or sheets, whichever is easier.

I've tried as much as I could find already online. And I can send a PDF, and I can send a Google Drive link which delivers an editable sheets doc; but I want the end user to be able to access/edit it even if they do not have Google Drive.

This one successfully sends an editable PDF:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
var message = row[1]; // Second column
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet'
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxx");
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [file]});
}
}
```

I tried this one, to be able to attach a document (hoping an editable excel file) but I get an error code saying that the document is missing (even though it's the exact same doc ID I use in the above, which works):

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
var message = row[1]; // Second column
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet'
var file = DocumentApp.openById("xxxxxxxxx");
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [file]});
}
}
```

I wanted it to send an excel file, but it won't even find the document even when I use the same doc ID that I use in the 1st syntax above, which works.

This sends an excel doc.. but recipient unable to open. Is this not formatting correctly?

```
  function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  try {
 /*var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();*/
 var ss = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxx");
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export? 
 key=" + ss + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var params = {
  method      : "get",
  headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true
 };
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob(); 
blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
MailApp.sendEmail("xxxx", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The 
XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});
} catch (f) {
Logger.log(f.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Got up to this.. which sends an excel formatted doc.. but the recipient is unable to open it. Is this not formatting correctly?

Comment: In your situation, a bit of troubleshooting is needed. So, where is the problem; creating the file? sending the file as an attachment?, is it at your end or with the recipient? I'd start with creating a spreadsheet that can be read in Excel. So par down your code to just build the spreadsheet, make sure you can open it, send it to the recipient, make sure they can open it. This answer by @Tanaike [Export a Google Sheet to Google Drive in Excel format with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49963724/1330560) might help.

Comment: I got the syntax to work:  function excelemail(){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1pJpDI2HD28_gPWGnj-emV0L4rXBBS0HC');
GmailApp.sendEmail('xxxx', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.'
                   , {attachments: [file],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
})}                 Now i just need to figure out/input a loop function to go thru the list of emails I have. Much thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax to send email from gmail with an excel attachment using google script

```
function excelemail(){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1pJpDI2HD28_gPWGnj-emV0L4rXBBS0HC');

GmailApp.sendEmail('xxxx', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.' , {attachments: [file], name: 'Automatic Emailer Script' })
    }
```