# Export Google Sheet as .xlsx and send file to server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My company manages non-confidential information in a Google Sheet. Every day, I export that sheet to .xlsx format and then upload it to various services for data syndication.

Normally, such a process could be automated using the "Publish to Web" feature. But for security reasons, that option is locked for all users.

I do have full permissions for Google Apps Script, though. So, I'd like to write a script for this. The particulars don't matter. Somehow, I need to export the sheet on a schedule and send it to an AWS server, where it can be automatically retrieved.

At the AWS side, I can easily set up an email server, FTP server, rclone, whatever. I just need to figure out what to do on the Google side first.

Can this be done?

What I have tried so far:

[Export a Google Sheet to Google Drive in Excel format with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963584/export-a-google-sheet-to-google-drive-in-excel-format-with-apps-script)

```
function makeCopy() {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm");
  var name = "Backup Copy " + formattedDate;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");

  // Added
  var sheetId = "2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name + ".xlsx"); // Modified
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```

--- OR ---

```
function convertSheetToXLSX() {
  var sheetId = "2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c";
  var spreadsheetName = "My Spreadsheet";
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sheetId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";  
  var params = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  blob.setName(spreadsheetName + ".xlsx");
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```

I have tried these scripts from the URL posted above but it results in "An unknown error has occurred, please try again later."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963584/export-a-google-sheet-to-google-drive-in-excel-format-with-apps-script

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief descirption of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I just added what I've already tried. As it happens, I've tried the method shared by Cooper.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About `I have tried the above script but it results in "An unknown error has occurred, please try again later."`, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your current script. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current script and situation, can you add your current script to your question for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: What was the problem because I just took the script written by MattMcCode and added a simple dialog ui and it works great.  It's on the same link that I gave you previously

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the script(s) I've tried. With MattMcCode's version, I get the error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Comment: I presume that you modified the spreadsheet id, the folder id and the filename.  I MattMcCode's version several times and it definitely works

Comment: cyberspectre, the "we're sorry, a server error occurred" will sometimes indicate a google side issue that will resolve itself. Maybe try again in a little while and see if it works again. That said, are you trying to run the AWS stuff in the same instance? Some parts of apps script seem to be more prone to this type of error, namely `UrlFetchApp`.

Comment: Update: I tried it with my personal Google account and it worked. So, this must be another permissions limitation...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835191/google-apps-script-send-pdf-instead-of-zip-file-in-email). It is about sending a spreadsheet in PDF format, but if you just change the `ExportOptions` to `xlsx`, you should be able to make it.